# Linux: How to grep for find values more than 100ms

Tags: linux, grep

I have a file in which a column has values which varies from 0ms to 15000ms. I want to grep rows which is having values more than 100ms. Please let me know how to do it?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: `\d{3,}ms`, perhaps?

Comment: Assuming that 9ms is not written as 00009ms, that should work, yes. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` it can be simpler (if `awk` is good for you), and it will also work if you have leading zeros like 001,002,..,00100, etc.

file1:

```
1ms
2ms
3ms
4ms
5ms
```

`awk ' $1>=3 ' file1`

Output:

```
3ms
4ms
5ms
```

Comment: this works only for numbers, check the output if the time is `10ms`.

Comment: it works even if the time is listed as 1ms, 2ms and so on

Comment: Try to enter `asasas` in the first field, to securize use: `awk ' $1+0>=100`

Comment: There is no input/output sample given by OP. We can only assume what it could be. Hence, I gave solution that works with numbers and also with `ms` format. The solutions can vary based on requirements, which currently is not complete.

Comment: `echo '10ms' | awk '$1>=100'` gives `10ms`. String comparison is not the same as number comparison. The trick with `+0` helps.

Comment: @Andrey your command `echo '10ms' | awk '$1>=100'` does not give me anything. I wonder how can this be different for you and me. It works for me. The trick with `+0` surely helps, but I am still not sure why the command without `+0` does not work for you.

Comment: I tested this with GNU awk 3.1.7 (CentOS 6.7) and GNU awk 4.0.2, 4.1.3 (Gentoo) with and without `--posix` option, I got `10ms` in all cases. Maybe you have different awk variant with more inclusive definition of "numeric string".

Comment: mine is GNU awk 3.1.7 (CentOS 6.6). The awk variant is same, still wondering :). Anyway there are solutions for both now so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Also tested in GNU awk 3.1.5 (CentOS 5.11) and 3.1.7 (CentOS 6.6), still got '10ms'. You're right, there is more robust solution. I'd stop here. If I could reproduce your result on any machine I have access to, I'd post a separate question about such different behaviour.